# libgdx change ambient light intesity

Tags: 3d, libgdx, light

I'm working on 3d app using Libgdx engine, and using 3d API.

I need to change intensity of the light over time.
I know there are three types of lights:
Ambient, Directional, Point.

Only PointLight has option for changing intesity.

I'm trying to change intesity of Ambiental and Directional light, using alpha component of Color that I set to the light.
But it's not working.

For example:

```
environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.1f));
```

and this:

```
environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
```

Are looking exactly the same, the same thing is with DirectionalLight.

Is there a way to achieve this???

Thank you!

Comment: Intensity = brightness?

Comment: Yes brightness. I guess i can proportionally reduce r g b components.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been my solution now.

Comment: How to acess again ambient light after I set it. I can easily access point lights and directional lights via environment.pointLights and environment.directionalLights. But I cant see how to access ambient light to change its brightness.